# Symfony/Doctrine - Create/update entity with OneToMany

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, updates, one-to-many

first of all, i'm sorry if that double post but I don't found any ressource with this issue or exemple that fix it and i don't understand what's going in his head.

I'm in Symfony/Doctrine and Vue/Nuxt on front,

So GOAL :
Update an array of entity (AideSection) where one prop is OneToMany for another entity (AideSubSection::AideSection)

Here exemple of the structure of my item :

```
[
  {
      id: 0,
      isActive: true,
      libelle: "",
      ordered: 0,
      aideSubSection: [
         {
             id: 0,
             isActive: true,
             isForDashboard: true,
             ordered: 0,
             orderDashboard: 0,
             aideSection: 0,
             libelle: "",
             content: ""
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

If I modify only data return by api and save , no problem, BUT when I try to save with new item, here is (partial) content of my post request:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfDvA.png)

So my ids are null, and here my controller and another file

```
#[Route("/backoffice/aide/save", name: "save_aide", methods: ["POST"])]
public function save(Request $request, AideSectionManager $manager) :JsonResponse
{
    $post = $request->request->all();

    /** @var AideSection $data */
    foreach ($post as &$data) {
        if (!empty($data['id'])) {
            $section = $manager->find($data['id']);
        } else {
            $section = new AideSection();
        }

        $form = $this->createForm(AideSectionFormType::class, $section);
        $form->submit($data);

        if (!$form->isSubmitted() || !$form->isValid()) {
            throw new Exception('Error');
        }

        $this->em->persist($section);
    }

    $this->em->flush();

    return self::response('ok');
}
```

Here my FormType

For AideSection

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
{
    $builder
        ->add('libelle', TextType::class)
        ->add('isActive', CheckboxType::class)
        ->add('ordered', IntegerType::class)
        ->add('aideSubSection', CollectionType::class, [
            'entry_type' => AideSubSectionFormType::class,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'allow_add' => true
        ]);
}
```

For AideSubSection

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
{
    $builder
        ->add('libelle', TextType::class)
        ->add('content', TextType::class)
        ->add('isActive', CheckboxType::class)
        ->add('isForDashboard', CheckboxType::class)
        ->add('ordered', IntegerType::class)
        ->add('orderDashboard', IntegerType::class);
}
```

My Entity (with relation)

```
class AideSection
{
#[ORM\Id, ORM\GeneratedValue, ORM\Column]
#[Groups('default')]
private $id;

#[ORM\Column]
#[Groups('default')]
private bool $isActive;

#[ORM\Column]
#[Groups('default')]
private string $libelle;

#[ORM\Column]
#[Groups('default')]
private int $ordered;

#[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: "aideSection", targetEntity: AideSubSection::class, cascade: 
["persist"], fetch: "EAGER")]
#[Groups('default')]
private Collection $aideSubSection;

#[Pure] public function __construct()
{
    $this->aideSubSection = new ArrayCollection();
}


class AideSubSection
{
#[ORM\Id, ORM\GeneratedValue, ORM\Column]
#[Groups('default')]
private $id;

#[ORM\Column]
#[Groups('default')]
private string $libelle;

#[ORM\Column(type: Types::TEXT)]
#[Groups('default')]
private string $content;

#[ORM\Column]
#[Groups('default')]
private bool $isForDashboard;

#[ORM\Column]
#[Groups('default')]
private int $orderDashboard;

#[ORM\Column]
#[Groups('default')]
private int $ordered;

#[ORM\Column]
#[Groups('default')]
private bool $isActive;

#[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: AideSection::class, inversedBy: "aideSubSection"), 
ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
#[Groups('default')]
private AideSection $aideSection;
```

Same problem on my AideSection, I don't understand why it doesn't detect or update ids from my AideSetion or AideSubSection :/

Answer (score 0):

Get the data from Form right after you checked if submitted and valid.
Then check if collection of aideSubSection isn't empty.
If it's not, loop through all, check if "new" (id is null) and persist.

```
if (!$form->isSubmitted() || !$form->isValid()) {
            throw new Exception('Error');
}

$section = $form->getData(); // gives you instance of AideSection
// dd($section); // check data

// loop through all
foreach($section->getAideSubSection() as $aideSubSection){
  // if "new" 
  if( $aideSubSection->getId === null ){
    $this->em->persist($aideSubSection);
  }
  // make sure they are "linked"
  $aideSubSection->setAideSection($section);
}

// persist only if $section is also "new"
if( $section->getId() === null ){
   $this->em->persist($section);
}

$this->em->flush();
```